# SESSION is not working in the PHP on different pages

Tags: php, session

I am working on a web application, there is a file called the initialize.php with the following code

```
<?php

ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.entropy_file', '/dev/urandom');
ob_start();
session_start();

require_once('database.php');
ini_set('log_errors', 'On');
```

I include this file in each of my page, when user click on the sign up button, singup.html file is loaded.
this form is posted to the singupstep1.php, which have the following code,

```
<?php
require_once 'private/initialize.php';
$professional['firstname']  = $_POST['first_name'];
$professional['lastname']   = $_POST['last_name'];
$professional['email']      = $_POST['email'];
$professional['password']   = md5($_POST['password']);
$errors = professionals::validate_pro_step1($professional);
if(count($errors) > 0) 
{
    //There are errors
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($errors); exit;
}
else 
{
    $obj    = new professionals($professional);
    $result = $obj->create();
    if($result) {
        $id = $obj->getLastInsertId();
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        header('Location: Subscribe.html');
    }

}
```

As you can see, I am setting the session variable, and redirecting user to Subscribe.html, When the Subscribe.html form is posted, the following code executed

```
<?php
require_once 'private/initialize.php';
if(isset($_POST['plumbing'])) 
{
    $professional['category'] = $_POST['plumbing'];
}
$errors = professionals::validate_pro_step2($professional);
if(count($errors) > 0) 
{
    //There are errors
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($errors); exit;
}
else 
{
    $obj    = new professionals();
    $id     = $_SESSION['id'];
    $result = $obj->update_one_column($id,'id',$professional['category'],'category');
    if($result) {
        header('Location: address.html');
    }

}
```

As you can see, I am starting session on this page as well, but the session variable is empty. I don't know what's wrong with the code or with the server. The issue I am facing is on both my pc and on cpanel as well, Please guide me what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Make the File extension should be .php it should not be .html

Comment: Well, I tried this way as well, this also did not seem to work, I guess there might be some sort of htaccess issue, or somehow, sessions are not being stored for among pages.